# How to get Modal to work past page 1 for datatables and Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I know I dont have code listed, but I still wanted to pose the question until I can get some code up.

Does boostrap 4 modals work on datatables on pages past 1?

It is not working for me. When I search or go to a different page of the table, the modal doesnt pop up.

```
<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
 <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Asset ID</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><button style='background-color: Transparent;border: none' data-id='16' class='asset_quick_view'><font color='blue'>A0016A</font></button></td>           
    </tr>

.... repeat for over 10 times to get more than 1 page

  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Asset ID</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>



<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Asset Info</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
        <script>
                $(document).ready( function() {
                        $('.asset_quick_view').click( function() {
                                var asset_id = $(this).data('id');

                                // AJAX
                                $.ajax( {
                                        url: 'get_asset_info.php',
                                        type: 'post',
                                        data: {asset_id: asset_id},
                                        success: function( response ) {
                                                // Add response in modal body
                                                $('.modal-body').html(response);
                                                // Display Modal
                                                $('#exampleModal').modal('show');
                                        }
                                });
                        });
                });
        </script>
```

Comment: found this.... https://datatables.net/faqs/index#events

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an delegated event handler on the table's tbody as shown in the [datatables example](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/events_live.html). As the table itself and its body will be stable (even after switching pages), the click listener will remain valid.

```
$('#example1 tbody').on('click', 'td', function() {
   // ... your code
});
```

Additional explanation on the jQuery website: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 0):

With a nudge from @Johannes, I was able to at least google the right terminology for the **delegated event handler**

In combination of the posted links and the search, I was able to successfully fix/handle the issue.

The biggest change declaring a table, changing 'tr' to 'button', and using $(this).text() to get the cell information of the button.

Not sure if this is ideal, best practices, or a solid solution but its working and used until told otherwise.

```
var table = $('#example1').DataTable();
$('#example1 tbody').on('click', 'button', function () {                                                                                           
  var asset_id = $( this ).text();
    <!-- ajax call -->
});
```